# Python Subprocess command with quotes and variables

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a complicated command that I want to run with subprocess. It contains single and double quotes and I want to drop in some variables.

This is the string:

```
gitlab create_merge_request 5 "{} - New merge request - {}" "{source_branch: '{}', target_branch: 'dev', assignee_id: 1}"  --json
```

I want to maintain the quotes around the 'New merge request' section (it contains two variables and around the 'source_branch' variable. The curly braces in the 'source_branch' section are also causing problems.

When I format the string like this:

```
gitLabCreateMerge = ('/usr/local/bin/gitlab create_merge_request 5 ', str(committerUser), ' requested - Automated Merge Request- ', str(reviewerUser), "'{source_branch:", str(branchName), " target_branch: 'dev', assignee_id: 1}' --json")
```

It looks like this:

```
('/usr/local/bin/gitlab create_merge_request 5 ', 'alice', ' requested - Automated merge request - joe ', "'{source_branch:", 'testdevbranch', " target_branch: 'dev', assignee_id: 1}' --json")
```

Comment: Can you please use more distinctive values than asdfasd, it will make the question easier to read. Write `committerUser = 'alice'` in the question, for example.

Comment: Fair enough. I've modified the last blob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With subprocess, you're better off passing a list of strings rather than a string to be evaluated by the shell. This way you don't need to worry about balancing your double quotes (and escaping potentially executable values).

The curly braces can be [escaped from string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) by doubling them.

With those two notes in mind, here's what I might do:

```
committerUser = 'alice'
reviewerUser = 'joe'
branchName = 'testdevbranch'
cmd = ["gitlab",
    "create_merge_request",
    "5",
    f"{committerUser} - New merge request - {reviewerUser}",
    f"{{source_branch: '{branchName}', target_branch: 'dev', assignee_id: 1}}",
    "--json"]
subprocess.Popen(cmd, …)
```

I'm using Python 3.6's [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498) here, but it could also be done with the `str.format()` method

```
"{} - New merge request - {}".format(committerUser, reviewerUser),
"{{source_branch: '{}', target_branch: 'dev', assignee_id: 1}}".format(branchName),
```

Or explicitly by concatenation, which might be more readable than trying to remember what the double curly braces are for.

```
committerUser + " - New merge request - " + reviewerUser,
"{source_branch: '" + branchName + "', target_branch: 'dev', assignee_id: 1}",
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm getting an error for one of the lines(sorry about the formatting):


 f"'{committerUser} - New merge request - {reviewerUser}'",
                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Subbing out the two f-string lines for your str.format() lines did the trick. Thank you!